When I try to install tensorflow in Jupyter I keep getting the error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow"
I am using Python 3.13.0(64-bit). I am trying to import tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook and I keep getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'. I run Jupyter Notebook locally.
So I upgraded my pip and tried to install Tensorflow using !pip install tensorflow. Then I get the error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

I tried installing Tensorflow. I upgraded my pip. I rechecked Python env variable path.
How to resolve this?

The error is with the Python version, right now according to the software requirements TensorFlow supports Python 3.9–3.12 (Install TensorFlow with pip). Since you're using Python 3.13.0, TensorFlow doesn’t have a compatible version for this Python release yet.
